# Meaning of the symbol $\oplus$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Anybody who knows/can explain what this character means?

[image]

Comment: It tells you it's the symmetric set difference.

Comment: Well it's said in the text

Comment: And it is encoded as `\oplus`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]The symbol is symmetric set difference,
$A \oplus B = (A-B) \cup (B-A)$.
The red colour portion shows the symmetric difference.

Comment: What does $\ominus$ and $\otimes$ mean ?

Answer (score 0):

This is symmetric difference:

$$A \oplus B:=(A-B) \cup (B-A).$$

It is the collection of elements in either of the sets, but not the intersection. Associativity is probably easiest using:

$$(A-B) \cup (B-A)=(A \cap B^c)\cup (A^c \cap B),$$

Where $A^c$ denotes the set theoretic complement.